# How place tab/pivot headers on the bottom screen windows 10 universal app?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

How I can make tab/pivot headers on the bottom screen in windows 10 universal app like in second picture?

I can`t find code example.

[image: Pivot]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC795444.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit the style of `Pivot` control.

In the designer view, right click on `Pivot` > Edit Style > Edit Copy.

So, I'm gonna post the whole style I got so far:

```
<Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="Pivot">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="BaseContentControlStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                                <Style x:Key="TitleContentControlStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}" TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleFontFamily}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleThemeFontWeight}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleFontSize}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisibility">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsHidden"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="HeaderDynamic"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="HeaderStatic">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="Header">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="StaticHeader">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{StaticResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}" Style="{StaticResource TitleContentControlStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="NextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                    <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform"/>
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LeftHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding LeftHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding LeftHeader}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">
                                                <ContentControl.Clip>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="HeaderClipperGeometry"/>
                                                </ContentControl.Clip>
                                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                                        <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform"/>
                                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform"/>
                                                            </TransformGroup>
                                                        </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                    </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                            <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" IsEnabled="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" Opacity="0" Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                                            <Button x:Name="NextButton" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" IsEnabled="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" Opacity="0" Template="{StaticResource NextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" x:Name="RightHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding RightHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding RightHeader}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">
                                                <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform"/>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                            </ItemsPresenter>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </PivotPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Why not include the code in your answer, instead of pasting a screenshot of some of it?

Comment: @RowlandShaw the complete code is long and full of indented parts that have nothing to do with the question

Comment: Hmm, I think is not correct answer. Because if i do it changes, result is:
[PrintScreen](http://s14.postimg.org/92sf3c68h/Capture.png)

Comment: @IgnasBagdonas let me know if the updated answer works